# ResourceSet not loading items in subfolders of subfolders

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I am using the typical code to load an assembly and retrieve its resources.  It finds all the resources that are in top level subfolders (e.g., "component/Images") but if I put resources such as images into subfolders of those (e.g., component/Images/MenuIcons") then none of those resources end up in the collection.  I've checked the application.g.resources file and they are in there.  I've tried two ways of scanning the resources:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
string resourceName = asm.GetName().Name + ".g";
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(resourceName, asm);
System.Resources.ResourceSet resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);
List<string> resources = new List<string>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resourceSet)
    resources.Add((string)resource.Key);
rm.ReleaseAllResources();
return resources;
```

And also:

```
foreach (string name in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
    {
            using (IResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(stream))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
                {
                     // Add resource here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods produce an identical result, but neither one includes any of the resources in subfolders of subfolders.  Anyone know how I can get a list of those?  They work just fine when referenced with pack: URIs.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem, with your code I can get resources for any level of subfolders, I even tried with 6 and it still works so something else must be your problem. When I tested this I noticed that I sometimes have to rebuild the assembly for the resources to show up, also the Resource Build Action is of importance, e.g. setting an image resource Build Action to Resource made it show up while it was skipped with None, Content etc.

Comment: I've rebuilt. Doesn't work for me on anything I've tried. There's nothing unusual about the assemblies in question.  Oh, and Reflector seems to not have a problem finding them.

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller sample application and assembly, and in that case, is the problem still there? Should I upload my sample application so you can try it to see if it works on your end?

Comment: Yes, tried with small stuff, too.

Comment: Do you think you need the SatelliteContractVersionAttribute?

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't applicable -- I have no satellite assemblies, there's only one version to load.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your resources are not copied to the bin directory on Build? Check the build Action and Copy To Output Directory properties of those files.

Comment: No, that is definitely not the issue.